# Is having class Thing that implements interface IThing a bad practice?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a certain class `Thing`, and an interface that it implements, named `IThing`. Everybody who uses `IThing` can presume that it's really a `Thing`, since it's the only class which implements this interface, but at the same time he understands that he can only access a certain subset of the public members of `Thing`, and there's a pretty good design reason for this — basically, `IThing` is a read-only version of `Thing` (it's a little bit more complex than that, but let's pretend it's just read-only/write distinction for the sake of the question).

Is it a good convention though? As an alternative, I could name this interface `IThingReadOnly` or name the class `ThingWritable`, or something like this, but it seems that these names would be bulky and less readable in a big codebase.

I also use extension methods extensively for both interface and class, so I have `ThingExtensions` and `IThingExtensions` as well. It's very useful, because everyone who reads the code of this extensions can operate from an assumption that it only uses public members of `Thing` and `IThing`, respectively. However, having both `ThingExtensions` and `IThingExtensions` files sitting alongside in a project seem a little bit off for some reason.

So, which one is a better option — to keep `Thing` and `IThing` alongside, or to rename one of them?

**Update about close vote**:

This is an opinion-based question, because it's question about best practice — but it's not a **primarily** opinion-based question (please mind the distinction). SO has a lot of great question and answers about best practices, so I think that either there's a difference between this question and other best-practice question that I don't see, or this question has just the same right to exist as any other best-practice question.

Comment: Is `Thing` marked internal and `IThing` public? Are `IThing` properties and methods explicitly implemented in `Thing`?

Comment: No, they are both public. Yes, they are explicitly implemented.

Answer (score 1):

First off I´d suggest using extension-methods just for types you do not have control on, e.g. the .NET-types like `IEnumerable`. However you may consider create two different interfaces, one base interface for reading (let´s call it `IThingRead`) and another one that represents your actual `Thing`-type (`IThingWrite`) with some write-modifiers.

Anyway creating an interface for every class is good practice and eases testing by mocking up some uof your types.

Comment: I don't plan to use these interfaces for mocking, so I don't really need `IThingWrite` — I only use a separate interface to separate the write access from read-only access.

Comment: Extension methods are very useful with types you do control if that type is an interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you will not need another implementation of the interface and you don't need to mock the interface for test purpose, you can simply remove the interface and use the concrete class.

Otherwise keep using IThing and Thing (this is the normal naming convention).
I would create only IThingExtensions though

Comment: I described another reason to use separate interface and class in the question.